# Upgradation of Windows phone 8 App to windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

We have created a net banking app last year for a bank. Now we are supposed to upgrade that app to Windows Phone 8.1. I know that windows phone 8 app will definitely run on Windows Phone 8.1. But I need to investigate how we can make the app experience better for the user by using new API. I have been searching over the internet on this could not find anything particular. Can you people please guide me what are the API/Namespaces that has been there in Windows Phone 8 but being deprecated in Windows Phone 8.1. Any pointer or any URL would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have option to build Windows Phone 8.1 Application using the `OLD SILVERLIGHT BASED API's` used in Windows Phone 8 as well as `NEW XAML BASED UNIVERSAL API's` which have convergence ratio of 90% between Windows 8.1 & Windows Phone 8.1. If you want to know the features that you can have in Windows Phone 8.1 application then I suggest you go through

1: [Building Apps for Windows Phone 8.1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1) Video Tutorials (At least first few) - This video series gives you the basics of Windows Phone 8.1 application developement

2: [Windows Phone 8.1 Development for Absolute Beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) This will also help you in understanding the basics & start developing WP 8.1 applications using NEW XAML BASED API's

3: [What's New in Windows Phone 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632424.aspx) Microsoft Documentation

You will find much more blogs on internet describing the differences between WP 8 & 8.1 but the above links will briefly cover the technical differences.
Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me please what are things that are in Windows Phone 8 are deprecated in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: By watching first 2 or 3 video tutorials of Building Apps for Windows Phone 8.1 series, you will know the API's (Features for developers) deprecated & new in WP 8.1. No one have made an entire list but this tutorials do explain them, here i have uploaded two images.